# SQL Query related to average and length

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i have a question. im currently doing an assignment, and having trouble in one particular request.
the request is:

```
Find Customers who have purchased more than 2 times. Get the
1. customer information
2. purchase frequency
3. total spending
4. avg basket size.
```

i already got 1 - 3, but i cant do much about number 4.
the values on product can have several values, separated by commas.

~> (product id: 12,4,5) -> if an order buys more than 1 product

i got to the point where i can separate it with length replace, but im a bit confused on how to show it to the average basket size.

thanks for any help!

SQL Table Image
[sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCalK.jpg)

```
**Customer**
Customer ID
Name
AddressCity

**Order**
OrderID
CustomerID
ProductID
Total

**Delivery**
DeliveryID
OrderID
AddressCity
```

this is my current sql statement

```
SELECT Customer.*, Order.CustomerID,
    COUNT(Order.CustomerID) AS PurchaseFrequency,
    SUM(Order.Total) AS TotalSpending
    FROM Customer JOIN Order 
    ON Customer.CustomerID=Order.CustomerID
    Group By Customer.CustomerID
    Having Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I suggest creating a temporary order2 table, fixing the design flaw in the current order table by parsing ProductID and creating a row for each Product, then update your query to match.  You will then have to also group by OrderID too.

Comment: Using SELECT Customer.*, Order.CustomerID.... GROUP BY Customer.CustomerID is bad SQL... it gives bad results read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: thanks for the help guys! cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LEN(Order.ProductID) - LEN(REPLACE(Order.ProductID, ',', '')) + 1
```

Should give you the total amount of products per order. 
Just add that to your existing statement.

```
SELECT Customer.*, Order.CustomerID,
    COUNT(Order.CustomerID) AS PurchaseFrequency,
    SUM(Order.Total) AS TotalSpending,
    AVG(LEN(Order.ProductID) - LEN(REPLACE(Order.ProductID, ',', '')) + 1) as AvgProdQuantityPerOrder
    FROM Customer JOIN Order 
    ON Customer.CustomerID=Order.CustomerID
    Group By Customer.CustomerID
    Having Count(*) > 1
```

**EDIT:**
The fields used in the SELECT part should also be specified in the GROUP BY part. Your query becomes then something like this:

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerID, Customer.Name, Customer.AdressCity,
        COUNT(Order.CustomerID) AS PurchaseFrequency,
        SUM(Order.Total) AS TotalSpending,
        AVG(LEN(Order.ProductID) - LEN(REPLACE(Order.ProductID, ',', '')) + 1) as AvgProdQuantityPerOrder
FROM Customer JOIN 
        Order  ON Customer.CustomerID=Order.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customer.CustomerID, Customer.Name, Customer.AdressCity
Having Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: ah yes.
but i think the request it to get Avg Basket Size / Average product quantity for each customer id. 
is it the same?

Comment: According to the data provided and the description I was assuming that "basket" is equal to "order".

Comment: Using SELECT Customer.*, Order.CustomerID.... GROUP BY Customer.CustomerID is bad SQL... it gives bad results read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: True that! I didn't pay much attention to the SELECT part.

Comment: this is the part where i say, i dont even know what i dont know .. haha.
so, any ideas to fix it?